# As It Tends To Be The Case

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about the usage of (or lack thereof) "*it*" in this [article](https://www.yahoo.com/sports/news/gary-kubiak-peyton-manning-gave-134400063.html):

> Peyton Manning's retirement press conference on Monday felt closer to a wake — he's not going to play football anymore, but he also is not dying. That is good news for lots of people (and Papa John).
>   ***As tends to be the case*** with wakes, folks took turns sharing stories about the departed, and Broncos coach Gary Kubiak had a pretty good one.

Would adding "*it*" between "*as*" and "*tends to be...*" be better?  Because this structure usually goes like these:

> As ***it*** appears to be the case...
>   As ***it*** seems to be the case...

Comment: Definitely *don't* add ***it***. [*As tends to be the case*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22As+tends+to+be+the+case%22): "About 4,300 results" in Google Books. [*As **it** tends to be the case*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22As+it+tends+to+be+the+case%22): 4 results. I suggest your *this structure usually goes like these* means that you haven't done much research yourself on this one.

Comment: Please leave this question open. We've seen way too much reasoning about grammar on the basis of the frequencies of phrases in a corpus. There are situations where "As it tends…" is correct and situations where "As tends…" is correct. It would be a fallacy to infer that because the former situations are rare, the former construction is ungrammatical. I hope to see a good answer to this question—but I don't expect that it will be easy to write.

Comment: It's simple inversion: As the case tends to be...., emphasis on **tends** by the inversion.

Comment: What the difference with dummy **it**????  As it so happens, I *do* have some money on me and can pay for this round! When we emphasize the verb in the simple present (tends), we emphasize the usualness of the fact expressed in the main clause. When we emphasize dummy **it**, we emphasize the unusualness of the fact expressed by the main clause.

Comment: the usualness of the fact,  or the likelihood of the conjecture, expressed in the main clause. As appears to be the case....versus.... as it seems.....

Comment: **as** wears many hats: it can be an adverb, a cojunction or a relative pronoun. There are also expressions like "as is" that seem to defy analysis. In this sentence it appears to be both a relative pronoun and a conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an adverbal phrase in which **as** carries the meaning of **like**.

```
As tends to be the case...
```

If you add an **it**, this would have the same function as **it** in sentences like "It is raining" and "It's not fair"... you are making an assertion, and **as** has the meaning **because**. The assertion must follow, linked by a conjunction...

```
As **it** tends to be the case **that** all wakes are boring, ...
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. Adding "it" changes the meaning of "as," and would be an incorrect edit to the quote.

Answer (score 0):

Building off what JavaLatte said, "as" in this case has a different meaning. It is prefacing the indication of a tendency. "As" indicates a clause which holds no meaning on its own, and in this case implies that what follows is normal or expected -- unsurprising.

In the similar-looking cases you mentioned, "As it seems," the "as" goes in front of a complete sentence, and would mean "because" or "since", and acts as a conjunction. The statement that follows is generally a complete sentence which could have meaning on its own.

To use "as **it** seems to be the case with wakes, ..." the natural question is "what seems to be the case, and why only with wakes?" It brings to thought the idea that some state is applicable specifically to wakes.

Answer (score 0):

No it, because you are talking about behavior which is currently not an 'it'.
Which means a definite thing. Behavior is a statistical property of groups.

> As tends to be the case {at} wakes, the room's acoustical behavior was poor.